# Transform solved - now wanting to add two additional table joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, pivot, transform

Currently, my final working transform in MySQL is working as needed. See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12d241/7) with query below:

```
SELECT idt.fldDRCClientID
    , idt.fldLastName
    , COALESCE(grp.fldCreditorName1, '') as fldCreditorName1
    , COALESCE(grp.fldDebtAccountNumber1, '') as fldDebtAccountNumber1
    , COALESCE(grp.fldEnrolledDebt1, '') as fldEnrolledDebt1
    , COALESCE(grp.fldCreditorName2, '') as fldCreditorName2
    , COALESCE(grp.fldDebtAccountNumber2, '') as fldDebtAccountNumber2
    , COALESCE(grp.fldEnrolledDebt2, '') as fldEnrolledDebt2
    , COALESCE(grp.fldCreditorName3, '') as fldCreditorName3
    , COALESCE(grp.fldDebtAccountNumber3, '') as fldDebtAccountNumber3
    , COALESCE(grp.fldEnrolledDebt3, '') as fldEnrolledDebt3
    , COALESCE(grp.fldCreditorName4, '') as fldCreditorName4
    , COALESCE(grp.fldDebtAccountNumber4, '') as fldDebtAccountNumber4
    , COALESCE(grp.fldEnrolledDebt4, '') as fldEnrolledDebt4
    , COALESCE(grp.fldCreditorName5, '') as fldCreditorName5
    , COALESCE(grp.fldDebtAccountNumber5, '') as fldDebtAccountNumber5
    , COALESCE(grp.fldEnrolledDebt5, '') as fldEnrolledDebt5
    , COALESCE(grp.fldCreditorName6, '') as fldCreditorName6
    , COALESCE(grp.fldDebtAccountNumber6, '') as fldDebtAccountNumber6
    , COALESCE(grp.fldEnrolledDebt6, '') as fldEnrolledDebt6
FROM tblClients idt
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT d.IndividualNumber as IndividualNumber
        , MAX(CASE WHEN row = 1 THEN d.fldCreditorName END) AS fldCreditorName1
        , MAX(CASE WHEN row = 1 THEN d.fldDebtAccountNumber END) AS fldDebtAccountNumber1
        , MAX(CASE WHEN row = 1 THEN d.fldEnrolledDebt END) AS fldEnrolledDebt1
        , MAX(CASE WHEN row = 2 THEN d.fldCreditorName END) AS fldCreditorName2
        , MAX(CASE WHEN row = 2 THEN d.fldDebtAccountNumber END) AS fldDebtAccountNumber2
        , MAX(CASE WHEN row = 2 THEN d.fldEnrolledDebt END) AS fldEnrolledDebt2
        , MAX(CASE WHEN row = 3 THEN d.fldCreditorName END) AS fldCreditorName3
        , MAX(CASE WHEN row = 3 THEN d.fldDebtAccountNumber END) AS fldDebtAccountNumber3
        , MAX(CASE WHEN row = 3 THEN d.fldEnrolledDebt END) AS fldEnrolledDebt3
        , MAX(CASE WHEN row = 4 THEN d.fldCreditorName END) AS fldCreditorName4
        , MAX(CASE WHEN row = 4 THEN d.fldDebtAccountNumber END) AS fldDebtAccountNumber4
        , MAX(CASE WHEN row = 4 THEN d.fldEnrolledDebt END) AS fldEnrolledDebt4
        , MAX(CASE WHEN row = 5 THEN d.fldCreditorName END) AS fldCreditorName5
        , MAX(CASE WHEN row = 5 THEN d.fldDebtAccountNumber END) AS fldDebtAccountNumber5
        , MAX(CASE WHEN row = 5 THEN d.fldEnrolledDebt END) AS fldEnrolledDebt5
        , MAX(CASE WHEN row = 6 THEN d.fldCreditorName END) AS fldCreditorName6
        , MAX(CASE WHEN row = 6 THEN d.fldDebtAccountNumber END) AS fldDebtAccountNumber6
        , MAX(CASE WHEN row = 6 THEN d.fldEnrolledDebt END) AS fldEnrolledDebt6
    FROM
    (
      SELECT @row := CASE WHEN tblClients_fldDRCClientID = @id 
          THEN @row + 1 ELSE 1 END as row 
        , @id := tblClients_fldDRCClientID as IndividualNumber
          , inf.fldCreditorName
          , inf.fldDebtAccountNumber
          , inf.fldEnrolledDebt
      FROM (SELECT @row := 0, @id := 0) v
        , tblDebtAccountNumber as inf 
      ORDER BY inf.tblClients_fldDRCClientID
    ) d 
    GROUP BY d.IndividualNumber
) grp
    ON grp.IndividualNumber = idt.fldDRCClientID
;
```

However, I want to take this one step further. I need to include/join two additional tables (*T3* and *T4*) to the mix. These two tables are both foreign key tables to the *tblClients* where:

- *idt.fldDRCClientID* is the PK of *tblClients*;
- *tblClients_fldDRCClientID* is foreign key for both *T3* and *T4*.

I have tried some additional inner joins and sub selects but they both fail. Looking for the proper places to add the syntax for *T3* and *T4* to get this functioning. Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: you can join them using any JOIN but the question is what is expected end result. also, i think your query can still be optimized lessening the use of nested sub-queries.